# Need column value from sql result based on other column value

Tags: php, arrays, database

I created a table in my database for translations. The structure of the table looks like this:

> TranslationId | FieldName | FieldValue | LanguageId

With a query I select all the translations for the desired `LanguageId`, which returns an array with rows. Now I want to use the `FieldValues` in this array in certain places, but how do I get the right `FieldValue` based on the `FieldName`?

So for example, in the header I need the `FieldValue` of the `FieldName` '*Header.Title*'. How can I get this specific `FieldValue` from my SQL result?

It would be easy just to print every `FieldName` and `FieldValue` with a loop, but I need specific translations at specific places.

Update:
Thanks Abra! Got it working now like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $values[$row['FieldName']] = $row['FieldValue'];
}

echo $values['Header.Title'];
```

returns the desired outcome.

Comment: Honestly there is not enough for us to go on. We'd have to see your table data and an example of your expected output, then we'd be able to help better.

Comment: A better solution would be create a separeted table for each idiom, and execute a join by WordId. Something like: "TablePortuguese as P
INNER JOIN TableEnglish as E on P.WordId = E.WordId"

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've already fetched the results into an array `$rows`, just extract `FieldValue` into an array indexed by `FieldName`:

```
$values = array_column($rows, 'FieldValue', 'FieldName');
```

Then use the `FieldName` as the key:

```
echo $values['Header.Title'];
```

You haven't specified the database API, but if you're building your own array from a loop then do it there instead:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $values[$row['FieldName']] = $row['FieldValue'];
}
```

Then use it the same way.

Comment: How could you possibly know any answer to this without any details @AbraCadaver? That's a lot of assumptions.

Comment: It seems pretty self-explanatory to me.  Not the "best" question but enough details.

Comment: I must be missing something then. As it stands this question is far too broad, shows no effort, has no MCVE.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you understood the situation and got me in the right direction. I have it working now, with a small change.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  What was small change?

Comment: I updated the original question with the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be create a separeted table for each idiom, and execute a join by `WordId`. If are You using MySql as I think, you may use the code below to do it.

Create a table for each idiom:

```
CREATE TABLE `english` (
 `WordId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Word` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `Synonym` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`WordId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `portuguese` (
 `WordId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Word` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `Synonym` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`WordId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Find the word translation and its synonym by id:

```
  SELECT E.Word, E.Synonym, P.WordId, P.Word FROM english AS E INNER JOIN portuguese AS P ON E.WordId = P.WordId
```